# Group and merge similar entries together using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a very large set of data currently stored into a vintage database. I want to extract them into a human readable format (YAML or JSON). The main goal here is to avoid redundancy by grouping similar entries.

My data can be summarized like this:

```
raw = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
       {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
       {'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 6, 'd': 4},
       {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 9, 'd': 9},
       {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}]
```

The goal is to group by column `a` and `b` and then combine similar entries together:

```
data = {
 1: {
     '2,3': {c:3, d:4}, 
      4:    {c:3, d:4} 
    }, 
 2: {
      2:    {c:9, d:4}, 
      3:    {c:3, d:4}
    },
}
```

Notice the keys `2` and `3` are joined together with a comma.

Eventually, my output file will look like this:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
1:
   2,3:
      c: 3
      d: 4
   4: 
      c: 6
      d: 4
2:
   2: 
      c: 9
      d: 4
   3:
      c: 3
      d: 4
```

Would it be easy to do the processing and get the `data` dictionary using Pandas?

At the end of the day I will use it as follow:

```
data = fetch_data(sql_query, groupby=('a', 'b'), group_similar='c')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
k = ['a', 'b']
result = {i: {} for i in df[k[0]].unique()}
for vals, data in df.set_index(k).groupby(list(df.drop(k, axis=1).columns)):
    for a, df_a in data.groupby(level=k[0]):
        res = df_a.reset_index(k[0], drop=True).to_dict('index')
        keys = ','.join(map(str, tuple(res.keys())))
        result[a].update({keys: list(res.values())[0]})
```

to get:

```
{1: 
    {'2,3': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}, 
       '4': {'c': 6, 'd': 4}},
 2: {  '3': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}, 
       '2': {'c': 9, 'd': 9}}
}
```

Comment: I will need time to fully understand it. This is a nice piece of code. That said, it does not work when fields `c` or `d` are empty *i.e.* `None`. In that case `df.set_index(k).groupby(list(df.columns.drop(k)))` does not iterate

Comment: I see . Are there any other conditions the solution has to meet that are not represented in your sample data? Btw, I think `drop(k)` needs `axis=1`, and `columns` should come after `.drop()`.

Comment: The sample data can have mixed scalar types `str`, `numeric`, `boolean`. The keys can be either numbers or strings. I think that's all for the conditions.

Comment: And of course, the number of columns can be larger.

Comment: But only `c` and `d` can be empty? Looks like this would be the only constraint for the proposed solution.

Comment: Oh sorry... the primary keys `a` and `b` cannot be empty, but all the remaining columns might.

Comment: That said I am trying to understand why it does not work and it is still not very clear.

Comment: Groupby automatically excludes missing values - see docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby. You could represent the missing values by some other value and replace after, if your data permit.